# Android/Ios in-app billing. unique ID

Tags: android, ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, uniqueidentifier

i made a cordova 3.3 app for Android and Ios, and i want to sell a premium version that permit to save settings and data for every on my distant database for an easy recovery if they change their phones.

Initially i thought to get their google/apple account email but it seems to not be possible.

So i thought that i just need an unique ID from the item purchased that i should use as an userID on my distant database.

I use this plugin for android:
https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling/tree/master/v3

So, the inappbilling.buy(success, fail, productId) and inappbilling.getPurchases(success, fail) both return a json object like this ex:

{"orderId":"12999763169054705758.1385463868367493", "packageName":"com.example.myPackage", "productId":"example_subscription", "purchaseTime":1397590291362, "purchaseState":0, "purchaseToken":"ndglbpnjmbfccnaocnppjjfa.AO-J1Ozv857LtAk32HbtVNaK5BVnDm9sMyHFJkl-R_hJ7dCSVTazsnPGgnwNOajDm-Q3DvKEXLRWQXvucyW2rrEvAGr3wiG3KnMayn5yprqYCkMNhFl4KgZWt-4-b4Gr29_Lq8kcfKCkI57t5rUmFzTdj5fAdvX5KQ"}

Can someone confirm me than **orderId** is strictly unique on android? (with source link or proof pls) ?

I will have the same issue on Ios, so do you know a if a value will can make the deal on Ios? I can't see the return value of the restore function in this plugin:
https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS

If it's ok for both, i could regist an ID like this :
"android_" + orderId
Or
"ios_" + ???
as user ID

Comment: On iOS I'm currently using productId + transactionId as an order identifier, but that may be excessive.

Answer (score 2):

Ok i found the answer on the ref... sorry.
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

"orderId : A unique order identifier for the transaction. This corresponds to the Google Wallet Order ID."
So i think it's ok for android. i will look on the Ios ref.

If you think about better idea for my case, feel free to add another answer.